# Error Django cms return TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, django

I want to start with Python and DjangoCMS, I follow this tutorial http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html, but when I execute

```
python manage.py cms check
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Jonatan\PycharmProjects\asesores2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Jonatan\PycharmProjects\asesores2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Jonatan\PycharmProjects\asesores2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Jonatan\PycharmProjects\asesores2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Jonatan\PycharmProjects\asesores2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 142, in create
    if not issubclass(cls, AppConfig):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Pip list

```
Package               Version
--------------------- -------
Django                2.2.6
django-classy-tags    0.9.0
django-cms            3.7.0
django-formtools      2.1
django-sekizai        1.0.0
django-treebeard      4.3
djangocms-admin-style 1.4.0
mysqlclient           1.4.4
pip                   19.0.3
pytz                  2019.3
setuptools            40.8.0
sqlparse              0.3.0
```

Comment: make sure INSTALLED_APPS has `'sekizai',` not `'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',` which need to be under Template Options

Answer (score 0):

Using the methods on that link also got me that error.

Try using djangocms-installer. instructions below.

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html